# How can I git rebase to merge two commits, one is farther and one is recent

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I want to merge two commits. One is farther back and the other is the recent one in my git history. Here is my last 12 commits in a branch (not in master).

```
$ git log -12 --pretty=oneline
47c724a6fdbb6a0b6d51cd42d0bde92c23a0d32e L 
9446932bc6e13d0437ab6b3f03161e3c2bca0f62 K Follow up of A
842e6a97284a02a70122d50f2f647a51b0e5cce7 J
77a0e99a62d9f77044cc37cbe22870b11c83f046 I
a125f0f701732a2dbd0cfe85c65583c46d1c67fa H
544b241dfe56e3b548af04c4d7c6e2092f3e108d G
7e5a649681a97f23c11716e8c87dfb1cc7d6125d F
d5378ec4216dce45dc0fc4a4ea1c0e4dac41a329 E
8d0420fd97178908db966a03d58252d5fb2b1c82 D
0e4425a86ce522a1a25886587c57379c1b4522ff C
5cba291aba6bb10749e1f1d4e0970d7e42decc17 B
2ba31cd61724f14f84a1a0a3e26e788374c62f9d A
```

There are many commits before A, but I think they are off-topic here and I did not list them.

I want to merge A and K. If possible, I want to delete A or K or both after merge. I've found some questions here about `git rebase --interactive`. I tried `git rebase -i HEAD~12` and I was brought into VIM. Then, I'm stuck and I can't proceed.

- I tried `edit` on K, but it seems editing the commit message only.
- I tried `squash` on A and K, but I got `Cannot 'squash' without a previous commit`. It seems squashing two subsequent commits only.

Can you please advice what I should do here? I'm free to `push -f` to the remote branch.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with Vim or can that tag get removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `rebase -i HEAD~12` you'll get your commits in order A (at the top) to L (at the bottom. Just re-order them so that K follows on A and instead **pick** choose **fixup** and save that buffer and exit vi.

```
pick 2ba31cd61724f14f84a1a0a3e26e788374c62f9d A
fixup 9446932bc6e13d0437ab6b3f03161e3c2bca0f62 K Follow up of A
pick 5cba291aba6bb10749e1f1d4e0970d7e42decc17 B
pick 0e4425a86ce522a1a25886587c57379c1b4522ff C
pick 8d0420fd97178908db966a03d58252d5fb2b1c82 D
pick d5378ec4216dce45dc0fc4a4ea1c0e4dac41a329 E
pick 7e5a649681a97f23c11716e8c87dfb1cc7d6125d F
pick 544b241dfe56e3b548af04c4d7c6e2092f3e108d G
pick a125f0f701732a2dbd0cfe85c65583c46d1c67fa H
pick 77a0e99a62d9f77044cc37cbe22870b11c83f046 I
pick 842e6a97284a02a70122d50f2f647a51b0e5cce7 J
pick 47c724a6fdbb6a0b6d51cd42d0bde92c23a0d32e L
```

Comment: You mean `fixup` at **K**? `fixup` at **B** seems merging **K** into **B** and removing **B**. I don't want to touch **B**.

Comment: `fixup` at **K** instead of **B** really did what I wanted. Thank you for your help. Accepted!

Comment: Right, on K. I've changed my answer.